# perl - one liner to loop through and kill pids

Tags: perl

How do I execute the `kill -9` in this perl one liner? I have gotten down to where I have the pids listed and can print it out to a file, like so:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep |grep /back/mysql | perl -lane '{print "kill -9 $F[1]"}'
```

Comment: I learned a little trick to get rid of the extra grep, try ` grep /back/mysq[l]`.

Comment: Doesn't mysql store its pid for you? Why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: As a general aside, avoid doing a `kill -9` on anything you don't have to! This signal can't be caught and therefore doesn't give a process a chance (if written so) to cleanup temporary files and shared memory segments.  Start with a `kill -hup` and escalate as necessary.  To find a process's basename look to the `-o cmd` option of `ps` as ikegami notes below.  More fuzzy matching to the whole `ps` line can be dangerous if done casually as you can match the wrong thing(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, heavily edited from my original answer.

First, the straightforward answer:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep |grep /back/mysql | perl -lane 'kill 9, $F[1]'
```

Done.

But `grep | grep | perl` is kind of a silly way to do that.  My initial reaction is "Why do you need Perl?"   I would normally do it with `awk | kill`, saving Perl for more complicated problems that justify the extra typing:

```
ps -ef | awk '/\/back\/mysql/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

(Note that the awk won't find itself because the string "\/back\/mysql" doesn't match the pattern /\/back\/mysql/)

You can of course use Perl in place of awk:

```
ps -ef | perl -lane 'print $F[1] if /\/back\/mysql/' | xargs kill -9
```

(I deliberately used leaning toothpicks instead of a different delimiter so the process wouldn't find itself, as in the awk case.)

The question then switches from "Why do you need perl?" to "Why do you need grep/awk/kill?":

```
ps -ef | perl -lane 'kill 9, $F[1] if /\/back\/mysql/'
```

Comment: you are right, i don't need perl. thought i would try it with perl. thanks.

Comment: See my edited answer; I included how to do it with Perl.  I was just trying to simplify.

Comment: Re "but I still wouldn't use it to do the actual killing:", why not?

Comment: @ikegami: I have reconsidered my position on that.  See edited answer above.  It was really a case of "I wouldn't normally use perl in the first place"; once you have perl in the pipeline, no sense not using it to do the whole thing.

Comment: Leaning toothpicks wouldn't be necessary if you checked the appropriate `$F[]` element instead of `$_`.

Comment: @ikegami: true, but then you need to know what the appropriate index for @F is.  which might change with date format/how old the processes are.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered [pkill or pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)?

```
pkill /back/mysql
```

or

```
pgrep /back/mysql | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's use a more appropriate `ps` command, for starters.

```
ps -e -o pid,cmd --no-headers |
   perl -lane'kill(KILL => $F[0]) if $F[1] eq "/back/mysql";'
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of extra typing. :)

Comment: @Mark Reed, Then good thing I did the typing has already been done for the OP, then?? I'm not sure what your point is. This is obviously not a one time use script.

Comment: I'm not sure that's obvious; I inferred that it was, and OP was just looking for how best to do that part in the future.  But it wasn't a serious objection (hence the smiley).

Comment: +1 for specifically pointing out that you want to match the command (basename) of a process.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep |grep /back/mysql | perl -lane 'kill(9, $F[1])'
```

The [`kill`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) function is available in Perl.

You could omit the two `grep` commands too:

```
ps -ef | perl -lane 'kill(9, $F[1]) if m%/back/mysql\b%'
```

(*untested*)

Comment: `$_ !~ m%\bgrep\b%`  ====>  `!m%\bgrep\b%`

Comment: Note that as written, this perl will also find itself.

Comment: @Mark; probably; you could `kill(9, $F[1]) if $F[1] != $$ && $_ =~ m%/back/mysql\b%`.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using even more Perl?

```
ps -ef | perl -ane 'kill 9,$F[1] if m{/back/mysql}'
```

Comment: FWIW, I came around to your way of thinking, @mob.  Note, however, that your solution runs the risk of Perl killing itself.  You either need to add something in place of the 'grep -v grep', or change the regex so it doesn't match itself (which is why I used leaning toothpics instead of m{...} in my answer).

Comment: @Mark Reed - that's a good point. Lots of options for avoiding leaning toothpicks: `m{/[b]ack/mysql}`, `m{/b(a)ck/mysql}`, `m{/ back / mysql}x`, ...

Comment: sure, I just stuck with the leaning toothpicks since I was modifying an awk example and leaving them alone got the job done.  From the command line I usually use gpoj's trick of sticking brackets around one letter.